# shielded cat 6 cable

Tags: cable, cat6

I am installing shielded cat6 cable for a building and i noticed that the green and blue pairs in the cable are thicker than the orange and brown pairs. I tried to install a cat6 rj45 but the pairs that where thicker did not fit. Is there a specific connector for this type of cable?

Answer (score 1):

You should be installing a shielded RJ45 plug if you want to actually make use of the shielding in the cable, but as for different sized internal cables, it's not something I've ever heard of, sounds like someone deviating from standards to sell their own marked up accessories..

CAT6 wires are thicker, but all 8 wires are thicker.

"CAT 6 Cable has a slightly larger diameter for each of the individual 8 wires within the jacket. Standard CAT 5E RJ45 plugs are designed to accommodate the smaller gauge CAT 5E Cable, and these plugs are designed with very close tolerances."

Comment: Ive never seen it either. I tried a shielded connecter as well for cat6 and it still didnt fit.

Comment: I'd be asking your supplier some pointed questions, especially about their refund/exchange policy.

Comment: I wish i could..im currently deployed and this cable was here for us when we got here. do they make different rj45s for different gauges of wire?

Comment: CAT6 wires are larger gauge, but it should be every single cable, not 1 pair.

Comment: i appreciate the help. Ive worked with cat6 numerous times, but i have never seen cable like this. Ill have to figured where we got it and call the manufactuer. Thanks again for the help